# Reduce height of a UIView from the top

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I am simply trying to set `frame` of a `UIView`, but when you try to reduce the `height` of view, it will be reduced from the bottom of the view, not the top. How can I change hight of view from the top of it not bottom ?

```
 customView = CGRect(x: 0, y:0 , width: self.view.frame.width , height: self.view.frame.height - reduceHeightSize)
```

Comment: show your code.

Comment: Do you want to cover top part of subviews?

Comment: you used constraints or programmatically creating the view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured it out what I need:

```
  customView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.view.frame.origin.y - reduceHeightSize , width: self.view.frame.width , height: self.view.frame.height + reduceHeightSize)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can update frame.origin.y as much as the height.

if reduceHeightSize is positive;

```
customView = CGRect(x: self.view.frame.origin.x, y: self.view.frame.origin.y + reduceHeightSize , width: self.view.frame.width , height: self.view.frame.height - reduceHeightSize)
```

if you store it negative reduceHeightSize;

```
customView = CGRect(x: self.view.frame.origin.x, y: self.view.frame.origin.y - reduceHeightSize , width: self.view.frame.width , height: self.view.frame.height + reduceHeightSize)
```

It would be better to just keep amount of the size not the direction.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do like...

```
customView = CGRect(x: 0, y:reduceHeightSize , width: self.view.frame.width , height: self.view.frame.height - reduceHeightSize)
```

Comment: Yes but as I said it will be reduce from the bottom not top

Comment: I don't think this code will work. It assumes the Y origin *before* reducing the size is 0.

Comment: Whenever size of a view is changed/reduced, it will always reduced form bottom, coz x and y of the view remains same....so if you want to reduced the view size from top....then you need to adjust y position of a view...Note: UI of the view is changed...content of the view remains as it is.

Answer (score 0):

`customView = CGRect(x: 0, y:0 , width: self.view.frame.width , height: self.view.frame.height - reduceHeightSize)`

The problem of your code is that you change `Height` in `CGRect`. and you want to change  top  position of `view` so you need to change position of also `y` of your view so finally your code will be

`customView = CGRect(x: 0, y: reduceHeightSize , width: self.view.frame.width , height: self.view.frame.height - reduceHeightSize)`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, that's probably because your view is not constrained/anchored at the bottom and thus defaulting to reduce on the top. Try adding a bottom constraint.